# Duplicate product in frontend

Tags: magento-1.7

Some **products are duplicate** in my homepage. Only name and descriptions are same. No image is showing for the duplicate record. And when I move cursor over it then the link redirects me to 404 Page . In the backend(admin) when I search that duplicate product by its link(name) then **I found nothing**.
For ex:- In the backend a product has following...

Product name:- Powerlock 3m/10ft 0-523
id :- 311
SKU :- STA033523
Website :- abc.com

Product name:- Powerlock 3m/10ft 0-523
id :- 12
SKU :- STA033523 Amazon
Website :- abc.com

In frontend :-

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$_productCollection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_featured', 1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
    ->joinField('value','catalog_product_entity_tier_price','value', 'entity_id=entity_id','{{table}}.website_id='.$storeId, 'left')
    ->setPageSize(9)
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId);  
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(180); ?>" alt="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>" />
        </a>   
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It was good . But suddenly today it shows duplicate.No changes has done.

I can't understand how to solve this issue ?
Kindly suggest how to deal with it ?
Thanks.

Comment: Re-indexing and clear cash to admin end

Comment: @Abdul I have done this already. Kindly look into the updated information.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the visibility filter to the collection..

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
```